# Create empty generic IList<IMyInterface> in c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a method returning a generic of an interface: `IList<ISettingIdentifier>`.

Now I want to return an empty list. But I can't get it working.  It builds, but I get an invalid cast exception.

```
public IList<ISettingIdentifier> GetEmptyList() 
{ 
    return (IList<ISettingIdentifier>)new List<SettingIdentifier>(); // THROWS invalid cast excption
}
```

How do I return an empty list?

Comment: `return new List<ISettingIdentifier>()`?

Comment: @DavidG thanks.  This was too obvious.

Comment: Sometimes we get too close to the code to see the really obvious things :)

Comment: Too bad i got minus 4 for reputation. :-)

Comment: @dampee You can delete your question, since it is not actual anymore. Also, any reputation changes will be reset.

Comment: Your method is dangerous. What if when I get your list with this method, I try to insert an instance that implements ISettingIdentifier, but that is not a SettingIdentifier ? You will get an error (an that is why your cast doesn't work). You should really do what @DavidG said.

Comment: @romain-aga It's not dangerous, it's just no possible to do.

Comment: @DavidG, Well, even if it's impossible, the idea is. And I think, it's important to point it out. If you aren't aware of this design problem, you will bring again this kind of design.

Comment: It was just too late at night when I was looking over something obvious.  new List<IMyInterface>() is the best solution indeed.